# GSOAP: enabling keep alive in gsoap

Tags: gsoap

I need to enable keep alive in gsoap.

I tried it by setting `soap.keep_alive = 1` and setting the keep alive flag for input/output modes.
But still I am not observing keep alive messages in wireshark.

How to enable keep alive in gsoap and what are the necessary parameters to set ?

Answer (score 2):

To enable keep-alive support, you need to set the flag `SOAP_IO_KEEPALIVE` when you initialize runtime with `soap_init2()`

[TCP and HTTP Keep-Alive](https://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc19.11)

> gSOAP supports keep-alive socket connections. To activate keep-alive
>   support, set the SOAP_IO_KEEPALIVE flag for both input and output
>   modes, see Section [9.12](https://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc9.12). For example

```
struct soap soap;
soap_init2(&soap, SOAP_IO_KEEPALIVE, SOAP_IO_KEEPALIVE);
```

> When a client or a service communicates with another client or service
>   that supports keep alive, the attribute soap.keep_alive will be set to
>   1, otherwise it is reset to 0 (indicating that the other party will
>   close the connection).